# Kubernetes/Container engine HTTP API for creating pods

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to create pods using HTTP.

I created cluster using:

```
gcloud preview container clusters create
```

and I can create pod using:

```
gcloud preview container pods create
```

But this is not what i want. I want to create pods with instance of my application via http API.

There is [API](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/v1beta1/) where I can create clusters. But I need something like this for creating pods. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694346/accessing-kubernetes-api-on-google-container-engine) (asked yesterday) and has the same answer:

Once you launch your container cluster on Google Container Engine, you will have a master running the kubernetes API on a VM in your GCP project. You can interact with it via the [kubectl command line client](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/kubectl), or you can extract the credentials for the cluster using gcloud and make HTTPS (but not HTTP) calls using the REST API exposed by the master.

Comment: kubectl is used by comand line, how should i set up cluster to make possible call it via HTTPS?

Comment: kubectl is a command line wrapper around the HTTPS API. You can talk to the API directly via HTTPS instead if you want. You can browse a visual version of the API at http://kubernetes.io/third_party/swagger-ui/.