# How to authenticate against Kubernetes clusters running on Google Container Engine using REST API?

Tags: rest, google-oauth, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bearer-token

I'm writing an application to monitor a kubernetes cluster running on Google Container Engine. On the host where my application deployed, there are no `kubectl` and `gcloud` CLI nor are they allowed to be installed. So I am trying to do everything through REST API.

For creating the cluster through REST, I can use [GCE Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/) with bearer token retrieved from [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Something like:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "Authorization: Bearer $MyBearerToken  https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/zones/$ZONE/serverconfig
```

I can also find [Kubernetes REST API reference here](http://kubernetes.io/kubernetes/third_party/swagger-ui/). So my question is: **How do I retrieve, say pod information, from my GCE Kubernetes cluster, using REST api and REST api only?**

I tried with `kubectl get pods --v=8`, and it's using `GET https://${Kubenetes_IP}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods`. But when I use the same api endpoint to curl with my GCE bearer. It gives me `Unzuthorized` error message.

```
# curl --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer $MyBearerToken" https://${Kubenetes_IP}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
Unauthorized
```

I am guessing because I need to use a different bearer token, or some other authentication method. I am wondering if anyone got a quick programtic one-liner? (Without resorting to `kubectl` or `gcloud`)

---

**Reference**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598405/3806343) affirms that there *is* a way using bearer token, but didn't give a pointer or example

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28700532/3806343) also seems promising, but all the link provided are broken (and api are deprecated as well)

[This answer](http://blog.ctaggart.com/2016/09/accessing-kubernetes-api-on-google.html) assumes `kubectl` and `gcloud` are installed, which is not allowed in my current use case.

Comment: I tried exactly what you did (get a token from the OAuth playground and use it to curl my GKE master) and it worked. Is it possible that the token expired?

Comment: @CJCullen I am able to curl GKE master as well (retrieve clusters info etc), but not able to curl the kubernetes itself (retrieve pod information, start a container etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the "GKE master" as the thing that serves the Kubernetes API. I did exactly this: `curl --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer $MyBearerToken" https://${Kubenetes_IP}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods` with a cloud-platform token I got from the Google OAuth Playground, and it worked for me. The "Unauthorized" error is a 401 from Kubernetes, suggesting that it doesn't like the token you are sending.

Comment: @CJCullen You're right! It must've somehow expired. I read it somewhere saying the token never expires, but I might be mistaken, or they were referring a different type of token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token can be retrieve from [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Kubernetes can be reached by the following `curl` command via REST API

```
# curl --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer $MyBearerToken" https://${Kubenetes_IP}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

Kubernetes Master IP can be retrieved with `kubectl get pods --v=8` and it could probably be retrieved somewhere from GCE Web GUI as well.

Full Kubernetes REST API can be found [here](http://kubernetes.io/kubernetes/third_party/swagger-ui/)

Make sure the token has not yet expired, and I think right now the default TTL is 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

When you authorize the OAuth2 playground to give you a token, it exchanges an [Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) for a [Refresh Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) and an [Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4).

The Access Token (from the OAuth2 playground) is valid for 1 hour.

The Refresh Token is a long-lived credential that is used to obtain new Access Tokens from the Authorization Server.

If you try to authenticate to the "Resource Owner" (in this case, Kubernetes) with an expired access token, it will respond with an HTTP 401 error.